# A lot has changed ___ Larry came back from his summer vacation

Tags: prepositions, british-english

A lot has changed ___ Larry came back from his summer vacation.

> a. since
> b. after
> c. when
> d. then

May I ask what is the most suitable answer for this question? This is because intially I chose a. since but the answer is wrong. Anyone can help me in understanding the question? Why since is not suitable in this question? Thank you in advance.

Comment: (a) is clearly correct. Are you sure it was marked wrong?

Comment: (b) is correct too (at least to my ears), but has a different emphasis.

Comment: "Stuart F Yes, 'after' is certainly acceptable if before / after change situations (not much of the observed change took place before before) are being compared ... but I had to re-read to see this possibility. As usual, a poor question is being queried. It makes it difficult when OP says 'this answer is wrong' when it's not (though perhaps wrongly stated to be wrong elsewhere).